# R: Can I assume stationarity if the adf test produces a p-value = 0.2413?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, analytics, p-value

Can I assume stationarity, considering the time series consists of just **26 observations**?

Is the *Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test* meaningful in this case?

If not, I'd ask which other tests may be more indicated for this specific situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually yes because you can not reject the H0 which says stationary  data. You are right that 26 observations is not much, especially if you test for different lags. But I also think stackoverflow is not the right place to discuss this...

Comment: You should probably ask your question at stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, the test works even with 26 observations.

But in your case the conclusions are completely different from what you have suggested.

The null hypothesis of dickey fuller test is unit root (e.g. y_t = y_{t-1} + e_t, depending on form of the test). With p-value of 0.2 you surely do not have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis of unit root.

In practice, it is good idea to have more data, as the test might not be so accurate for nearly non-stationary series.

You might also want to explore differences between dickey fuller without trend and intercept and dickey fuller with trend and intercept. If there is reason to believe you have no trend in the data, the dickey fuller without trend might provide better results (and maybe even lead to rejection of unit root)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Theoretically the time series should be stationary: How do I perform the dickey fuller _without trend_ ? The entire series of 46 observations returns a p-value of 0.01, but I can use the 26-long only for my work.

Comment: `ur.df(yourSeries, "drift")` or `ur.df(yourSeries, "none")` from the `urca` package can do this. But if you have already obtained this low p-value then even the test without trend will likely conclude stationarity, as it is comparing the test statistic to lower critical value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand I can state stationarity because of ur.df **and** the stationarity of the overall series.